# How to download a file stored as Binary in MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I am using MeteorJs, MongoDB and React. I want to simply make a module to upload/download files and store them in a MongoDB collection. So far, I can upload the file but I don't know how to download it.

This is the method in server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'saveFile': function(one){
      ChivoFiles.insert({data:one.buffer})         
  }   
});
```

This is the upload in client:

```
uploadFile(event) {  
    var file = event.target.files[0]; //assuming 1 file only
    if (!file) return;
    var reader = new FileReader(); //create a reader according to HTML5 File API
    reader.onload = function(event){          
      var elBuffer = new Uint8Array(reader.result) // convert to binary
      const one= {buffer: elBuffer}
      Meteor.call('saveFile', one);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

 <input type="file" id="fileinput" disabled={this.state.inProgress} ref="fileinput" onChange={this.uploadFile}/>
```

And this is how it look in MongoDB Compass:
[image: enter image And this is how it look in MongoDB]

I would like to know how I can convert the Mongo document into a downloadable file. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is the following:

the saved data is an EJSON format of binary.
What you need to do is, is to create an [HTTP endpoint](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html), get the doc and manually link the data to an http route:

```js
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp'

WebApp.connecthandlers.use('/download', (req, res) => {
  const file = ChivoFiles.findOne(req.query.id)
  const binary = file.data

  res.writehead(200, { 
    'Content-disposition': `attachment; filename=${file.name}`
    'Content-type': file.mimetype
  }); // this is why you need to save the name and mime, too


  const filestream = fs.createReadStream(binary);
  filestream.pipe(res);
})
```

You can call this via HTTP GET `/download?id=01234567890`

### An easier way to manage files

There is very popular [Meteor-Files package](https://github.com/veliovgroup/Meteor-Files/), which handles file upload, download, permission etc.

It's the perfect solution for your use-case.

You can use it together with external storages (S3 etc.) or local storages (FileSystem, GridFs): https://github.com/veliovgroup/Meteor-Files/blob/master/docs/3rd-party-storage.md

It also represents your files as documents in a `Mongo.Collection`, so you can access file information and meta data, without actually downloading the files.

Downloading files is handled via `MyFilesCollection.link(fileDoc._id)` which creates a http-based download link for the file, represented by the fileDoc (which itself is created on upload).